# Eclipse RCP catching System out println

Tags: eclipse, rcp

in my plugin, I want to catch all `System.out.println`'s, something like a wrapper and want to change the color of some outputted text in a different color.
Need help pls.

Comment: Output from what? Are you talking about the output that goes to the Eclipse console? Possibly you want the `org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleColorProviders` extension point or maybe `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners`

Comment: I try it with `org.eclipse.debug.ui.consoleColorProviders`. But I think it is not possible to pick out specific text from console output to define custom color.
It can only overwrite color for `ID_STANDARD_OUTPUT_STREAM`.
For me I need different color for all occurences of specific text.